# `Object doesn't support property or method "matches"` error using `phoenix_html.js`

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I’m getting the

> Object doesn't support property or method "matches"

error in IE11 using `phoenix_html.js` that comes with PhoenixFramework which includes codes like `event.target.matches(…`.
Unfortunately I have to support IE11.
Is there a workaround? (hopefully something cleaner than having to modify `phoenix_html.js`)

Comment: Which version of `phoenix_html` are you using?

Comment: phoenix_html@2.5.0

Comment: Can you try upgrading to the latest? The current version doesn't use `.matches` on DOM elements anymore.

Comment: It works. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like there are many other methods in phoenix_html that IE11 doesn't like? querySelectorAll, defineProperty, etc.

Comment: I don't see any `querySelectorAll` or `defineProperty` in https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/master/web/static/js/phoenix_html.js.

Comment: Sorry, it was phoenix_live_reload.js. Actually I was in the Compatibility mode too.